# Does the Hebrew tally these numbers?

Tags: hebrew, daniel, translation-philosophy, astronomy

Some Bible versions seem to make an assumption when translating the text of Daniel 12:12.  Most  translate it as 1335 days but that is not actually what it says!  The Authorised Version (and some others) write,

> “Blessed is he that waiteth, and cometh to the thousand three hundred
>   and five **and** thirty days.” (KJV)

However for the sake of simplicity, modern translators have taken the liberty of adding the two figures together.

> “Blessed is he who waits and arrives at the **1,335 days**.”  (ESV)

In other words, should it be separated to, "1305 days plus 30 days?"

I suspect that we are dealing with an ancient soli-lunar formula and, if so, they might have been separated for a reason.  Can anyone with an understanding of Hebrew clarify whether these figures were tallied or separated in the original writing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dan 12,12:
לְיָמִ֕ים אֶ֕לֶף שְׁלֹ֥שׁ מֵאֹ֖ות שְׁלֹשִׁ֥ים וַחֲמִשָּֽׁה׃

Literally: to days thousand three hundreds thirty and five

The KJV has “five and thirty” instead of “thirty and five” because this was the more common way to express compound numbers in 17th-century English. None of this has anything to do with lunar or solar calendars.

Comment: I'm sure you are probably correct, could you provide a reference for 17th century number writing preferences?

Comment: *This was the more common way to express compound numbers in 17th-century English.* - German still preserves this feature, as do Dutch and Danish.

Answer (score -4):

The Spirit of Yahweh has blessed me with some revelations I'd like to share with like minded people. Key insights about the book of Revelation you may find invaluable, points on a couple verses most teachers miss that should help you see where we are in time better.

The first thing I hope to get you to consider is how the tribulation is not a time of suffering and hardship for the majority of the people in the USA, I mean no more than we are now, it's actually a time when our destiny is decided. Although, most people will have no idea that it's even here until the end. People will be getting married and giving their daughters away in marriage right up until the very end, as it was in the time of Noah so it will be. But there's more to this, a puzzle.

Metaphorically speaking we are put into a tribulator for this time to be sorted into one of three categories, the bride, guests, or others. The wrath of Yahweh comes in a short period of time immediately following this sorting. Please try to see how we cannot be in the judgments until we have been separated into the correct category, this happens during the tribulation. But we cannot be tribulated until any prior sentencing has been served. And you may be among the sentenced.

The lost tribes were sentenced and we can now determine this number of the years; whereof the word of YHWH came to Ezekiel (4:5), “For I have laid upon thee the years of their iniquity, according to the number of the days, three hundred and ninety days: so shalt thou bear the iniquity of the house of Israel.” But we know that we were not taken out of exile after these 390 years, due to the continued wickedness of our forefathers when they did not walk according to the terms of the covenant, as it is written in Lev. 26:18, “And if ye will not yet for all this hearken unto me, then I will punish you seven times more for your sins.”, so then 7 x 390 years is the sentence we are to bear the lawful punishment for being defiant.

If we are reckoning the days of exile goes 2,730 years from 721 BC, as many claim that's when it began, in my opinion this judgment was served in full at sunset on the final day of the Feast of Tabernacles (Sukkot) in 2009. I believe that day ended the punishment sentence due by the Exiles of Israel.
Allow me to provide compelling evidence the tribulation is not seven years of havoc for us, as I once believed it would be, instead things will be similar to how they have always been, right up until the very end. It's then that we are awakened, at the midnight shout of His arrival, when the Bridegroom comes. Remember the five wise virgins in the parable and what that story's about? So, we are awakened when it is time to gather in the field, that's a fact, the reality is we sleep right through the tribulation.

For this earthly realm the bowl judgments will come immediately following the tribulation period, the wrath of Yahweh comes at the end of that sorting, not during it. The sleeper will be awakened just in time to get out, before the hunters can take aim (by the way, they're here too), be caught up by fishermen and escape. You know we have been asleep for some time in the USA, maybe you can see how most people will not know the tribulation has even occurred until the very end, but I understand it's hard to see right now, so I will put a big flasher on this lewer.

Have you ever noticed how everyone concerned is watching for the two witnesses to show up, for another alter and for the sacri fices to start up, ever wonder about that? It's one reason why it can't go down like that. Seriously, who would fall for that act today, sitting on the Mercy Seat? Would you?

Most people are misunderstanding some important points about the abomination of desolation. For example, there is a historian named Josephus that said Daniel's prophesy of the abomination of desolation happened in 168 BC. A great point but there's more to this prophesy. If we can look beyond that, realize not all of what we read about in the Holy Scriptures is observed as occurring in our realm of existence. Consider for a moment if you can, this time around the reciprocal wheel we had defilement of Israel below and desolation of the Temple on high.

I feel most of us are not getting who the two witness are yet, I always believed they were two people because of coming from a Greek/ Roman mind set where I didn't get the Hebrew idioms, allegories, metaphors, etc. put into the text, especially those found within a mystical prophesy book like Revelation. The biggest leap forward in my understanding of this book came just after I recognized how the three series of judgments, commonly known as the seals, trumpets and bowls, were going on in three different realms of existence. That was huge.

In Revelation you have descriptions of everything from the Throne Room of Yahweh to this present world. The first thing we need to see clearly is how the seals primarily effect the Heavenly realm (Beriah), the trumpet judgments mostly effect the angelic realm (yetzriah) and the final group of bowl judgments directly impact the physical world (asiyah).

The events of Revelation are all leading to the uni fication of these three realms, long in the making Yahweh wants all things to be echad, so when we get to the end of each of these three series of judgments we see the seventh one will offer the idea of completion. Like when we get to Revelation 8:1, with the last seal being opened, the seventh seal, we find there comes a silence in Heaven. Why silence? It may be because silence is peaceful and honoring the end of Yahweh's judging of the seals series, a tribute to Heaven's recti fication at this point of completion. I suspect this silence has something to do with the unification of the name of Yahweh, because that's what's happening in the Heavenly realm (Beriah) about here.

Please try to see how there are three realms (Heavenly, angelic, physical) in which these judgments (seals, trumpets, bowls) are occurring and then weigh in how they might just be rolling down from the upper realm to the next lower one. It appears that completion of the seal judgments happens first as Yochanan's account lays out, as well as moving from the upper realms downward to the next lower one sequentially so they may be casting shadows down onto the next lower realm, like echo judgments coming through and throwing fallout down. As is above, so is below.

It's also important to recognize a few of the idioms as seen throughout this panoramic view of time that Yochanan is sharing with us so we know who the players of this age old controversy are. Prophetically speaking we see the sun is associated with Jacob, the moon with Rachel, the twelve stars with the Twelve Tribes, the woman is Israel, the child is the Messiah, the dragon is HaSatan, the seven heads are the seven empires of man, the ten horns are authority of the Lost Ten Tribes. When we see the ten horns on the beast we should realize that it symbolizes how the those ten tribes had given Babylon her authority. By incorporating into its system.

The bride is the 144,000 that did not de file themselves with pagan worship and so they are the virgins. They are spiritual warriors who receive a mark, like victims of the enemy do, but it's different. It's a special mark we don't see but is required so that spiritual entities can identify who's who. This 144,000 come from every tribe of Israel, marked in the tribulation they will follow the Lamb everywhere He goes during the millennium reign and are called for a special work. They will say salvation unto our Elohim who sits upon the Throne and unto the Lamb, but they must also confess of their and their father's iniquities because they have walked contrary to Him.

Seek Yahweh while He can be found, while He is near. A principal Yahweh uses in sealing anyone to be His servants to preach the full message of redemption is the individual must hear the truth, faith it, then through Yahweh's sovereign Grace, which is the unmerited power to do righteousness, they may experience regeneration. Afterwords, he may catch a vision of Yahweh's purpose for his life and yield his life to Him. This can be especially difficult today when Yahweh calls you to do things against your culture, your people, your family. This group of elect are going against the mainstream of their religion, maybe considered as against the nation they've been exiled into, many will consider them outcasts.

This group called the bride is very rare because there are only 144,000 of them throughout the world. I don't see them as Jews, or even as Christians, it seems as if the Christians have half the picture because they know who the true Messiah is and the Jewish people have half of the picture because they keep and walk in Yahweh's ways (Sabbath, Feasts, etc.). Each of these groups is missing half of the story though. It appears as if one is getting into the Kingdom but the other is not, and neither of them is of the 144,000. This special group appear to be the ones who follow Yahweh's commandments and hold the testimony of Yashua. That is two things. Both.

The elect are rare breed around here because our society encourages us to adopt the way of the heathen. They are considered virgins, this implies they do not follow the ways of a nation so they probably don't even participate in national celebrations like the Fourth of July or Gregorian New Year (not to mention some festivals with a darker history). I suspect something much more scary is going on with the Jewish people because they don't know the King, so how can they possibly get in the Kingdom without the correct testimony? No matter how perfectly they follow Yahweh's Holy Days and His other statutes and ordinances it just seems like they're stuck, outside. Yes indeed, the elect are a rare breed.

The woman is Israel and they include the grafted in people. They are Yahweh's people and we get this kind of vision that HaSatan was always lying in wait for her, especially when Messiah was born, so it is with the tribulation. During the tribulation Yahweh allures her, the lost sheep of Israel scattered throughout the nations, into the wilderness by calling her out one at a time and He nourishes her there. She seems to be hidden from the face of the serpent during this last half of the tribulation period and afterwards Yahweh gives her the valley of A-chor for a door of hope. Any who miss that door may be caught up in the war with the saints that's coming soon from the anti-messiah and be overcome.

One purpose of the book of Revelation is to encourage Yahweh's people to hang in there until the end. With these corner pieces in on this large puzzle we can start seeing the bigger picture, we don't have to martyr ourselves at the end, let's wake up to the greater second exodus. I have seen enough evidence to convince me that this is what will be happening next, not the rapture as I was programmed with, I can now see how the lost tribes are ending the exile and going to collect on their inheritance.

Only when we see Yashua in the Torah can we make the proper connections for the reason and purpose of His ministry in His first coming (which is what He's teaching us in Mathew, Luke and John), thereby leading us to make the correct connections to His second coming. He seeks to come and to save what was lost. Israel, to restore Israel. It's an easy thing to do that, the hard thing is to get the correct message to the Gentiles. They certainly may come on board but the mission of Yashua's coming to this earth was to seek and to save what was lost, which includes her Kingdom of priests. If the nations will listen they can be incorporated into the Kingdom of Yahweh, but that's what He came for, for what was lost.

Judah and Israel were separated a long time ago, Israel was scattered, eventually all over the earth and now they are considered the Ten Lost Tribes. That's us. I am not talking about the land of Israel here but the lost sheep, although most of Judah may be in the land today He is coming for the remnant that are scattered in the nations, to establish the Kingdom of Yahweh here on earth. That's 1,000 years here on this earth with our King Messiah teaching us the ways of the One Without End Or Limit. I currently believe this must begin before 2017, before seventy years have passed from the date of November 28, 1947. The reason I believe this is because it's the answer to the parable found in Luke 21:29-32.

When Your judgments are in the earth the inhabitants of the world learns righteousness. According to Luke 17:27 in the days of Lot they ate, drank, bought, sold, planted, builded... the same day it rained down fire and brimstone from heaven and destroyed them all, even thus shall it be in the day when the Son of man is revealed. If that's not clear enough tell me this, if people are still getting married and giving their daughters away in marriage right up to the end am I suppose to believe there's craziness going on all around them? Would you want to get married in Yahweh's wrath? My current belief is there's a day of disaster that's just ahead of us, one that may involve a miracle 1,000 times more magnificent than the Red Sea's parting in which the Lost Sheep of Israel will be saved from the enemy.

In my opinion the tribulation timeline follows the son of perdition's part in this marvelous play. When he comes in peaceably it begins and when he breaks that same peace covenant it will end, so he's really our Calendar cypher to identify where exactly we are on Yahweh's masterful itinerary. I suppose that's why he is made so obvious for us in scripture. The prophets gave us a lot on him so he's not hard to recognize with the piles of evidence available for any with eyes. But in case you have a spiritual handicap right now I can offer you some math that may help you see something. Numbers don't lie.

If we were calculating 5,000 years on the Gregorian calendar, we'd gradually loose time each decade until we are 50 days behind the solar cycle, but on Yahweh's Calendar we are within one half day of the correct time after that same time. That may not surprise you, but what might is how easy He made it. The Architect Of The Universe designed the adjustments of time into His Calendar so that for man's history it would be an easy thing to use. Most men didn't even have to write it down and really only needed to be concerned with two additions to it in their lifetime, a 30 and 45 day addition.

How easy was it? There were twelve months of 30 days each, you'd add 30 days to the Calendar each 7 years and that was a cylce, after that you'd go right back to your 30 day months and repeat another cycle. After completing 7 cycles you'd add an extra 45 days to your Calendar and that would complete a Jubilee cycle. So all we do is add 30 days each 7 years and another 45 days each 49 years. If you happen to be alive when 1,000 years passes on the Calendar or when 5,000 years comes around you'd do the same thing, just add 30 days for each of them. So the additions are simply 30/45/30/30 days at years 7/49/1,000/5,000 on the contiuous base pattern of twelve 30 day months. That's His Calendar.

If we were around thousands of years ago and used Yahweh's Calendar we'd know it has an adjustment every 7 years (2,520 days) that adds 30 days to it and at 49 years that adds 45 days, so we'd know the numbers 2520, 30 and 45 pretty well, I'd guess. If I was sharp I'd even know the numbers 2520, 2550, 2595 well, I suppose. But I don't see how we'd be familiar with the numbers 1260, 1290, or 1305 back then because these numbers are part of a future prophesy.

It seems the clue that the prophet Daniel gives us was meant for those who understand Yah's ways, which includes how the ancient Calendar system worked. Now when you read the numbers within the tribulation prophesy 1260, 1260, 1290, 1305, 30 your mind probably wants to connect them to Yahweh's Calendar and the adjustments therein, well, that's what happens when I read the numbers 1305 and 30. It also looks to me like a clue, one that helps solve the timeline puzzle of the tribulation period, revealed to those that might have knowledge of His Calendar workings and with the prophesy that says 'Blessed is he that waiteth, and cometh to the thousand three hundred and five and thirty days.'

Understanding the Blessed day is the wedding day and that it is 1305 days from the mid-point of the tribulation are paramount clues that people studying calendars have been missing. Clues necessary to find the exact dates of the tribulation's time period, that is, not Yashua's return day, but the sorting period before it. By identifying the 45 day adjustment period as Sukkot, then subtracting 1305 days and also the 1260 we should see it began on a Friday at sunset. This appears to be the date the son of perdition came in peacably, on a covenant with the many, the day following the final day of the exile judgment for the lost tribes.

My research convinces me March 22, 2013 was the exact midst of the week and September 2, 2016 at sunset will be the end of the tribulation period. However this date may not technically be the end of the 6,000 years. I currently feel it's the end of the sorting and preparation period that occurs before Jacob's trouble and that the wild stuff begins to happen right about here, stuff that involve the bowl judgments which will awaken the late sleepers. After the wrath of Yahweh has been completed then will come our Blessed Day.

If this resinates with you and you wish to discuss the matter further I'm seeking like minded people to talk with about these subjects in a pre-exodus meet up, so am coming out of the wilderness and will be down on the beach in Otter Rock Oregon on March 22, 2016 at noon, (latter) rain or shine. Exodus or rapture I'll be there, if you have insights on the greater exodus departure or on the true Calendar of Yahweh that are busting out of you right now then we should talk. Forgive me if the location is hard for you but this is where I've been called to wait at, in the wilderness. Yes, I'm the guy who actually came out of her, look for the simple looking guy holding a shofar.

As far as the revealing of the son of perdition goes, try not to be disappointed when he's unveiled to you, be happy that you have spiritual eyes that see. It's a blessing to have truth replace the uncertainty and doubt the enemy subverts into us and you know Yahweh's Spirit likes to hang out with truth. Actually, I suspect we were all programmed to fall for it (maybe a spell?). I mean somebody had to be the Deceiver and when you think about it for a while you may feel he played the role perfectly. Well, I'm impressed anyway, in my opinion he is killing it.

Servant of Yahweh.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  Please consider [registering an account](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to fully take advantage of what this site has to offer.  Also, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what we are about... This answer has potential, but also contains a lot of off-topic info and speculation. It would be greatly improved by removing information not directly related to the question and/or adding references to back your interpretation.

Comment: I admire your industry, but this is simply fanciful speculation. You state: "`...the numbers were originally separated for a reason...`". Correct. And the reason is: that's [how numbers](https://goo.gl/TYDOI6) are presented in biblical Hebrew.

Comment: more details can be found concerning this at Rapture Ready.